# MySQL Pivoting rows and columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some user data, and a second one with user properties data. The properties are always going to be 2, and I know their name. I need a query to retrieve everything in a single structure. I cannot alter, however, the database schema.

This is the simplified version of my database:

USER

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| username          | varchar(64)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name              | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

USER_PROPERTIES

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| username  | varchar(64)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| propName  | varchar(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| propValue | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

So, having for example, this data:

USER

```
username         name
1                User1
2                User2
```

USER_PROPERTIES

```
username         propName         propValue
1                status           "At work"
1                picture          "pict1.jpg"
2                status           "Busy"
2                picture          "pict2.jpg"
```

I would need the following result:

```
username         name             STATUS          PICTURE
1                User1            "At work"       "pict1.jpg"
2                User2            "Busy"          "pict2.jpg"
```

I did some research in Internet and apparently this is achieved with PIVOT, but MySQL does not contain this functionality. By following the answers here: [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table), I could manage to get this:

```
select ou.username, 
    case when (oup.propName='status') then oup.propValue end as 'STATUS',
    case when (oup.propName='picture') then oup.propValue end as 'PICTURE'
from User ou, User_Properties oup
where ou.username = oup.username;

username         name             STATUS          PICTURE
1                User1            "At work"       null
1                User1            null            "pict1.jpg"
2                User2            "Busy"          null
2                User2            null            "pict2.jpg"
```

The results are in two different lines. If I group the results by username, I get the PICTURE data always as null:

```
select ou.username, 
    case when (oup.propName='status') then oup.propValue end as 'STATUS',
    case when (oup.propName='picture') then oup.propValue end as 'PICTURE'
from User ou, User_Properties oup
where ou.username = oup.username
group by oup.username;

username         name             STATUS          PICTURE
1                User1            "At work"       null
2                User2            "Busy"          null
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

EDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry gave the solution:

```
select ou.username, 
    MAX(case when (oup.propName='status') then oup.propValue end) as 'STATUS',
    MAX(case when (oup.propName='picture') then oup.propValue end) as 'PICTURE'
from User ou, User_Properties oup
where ou.username = oup.username;
```

Comment: Max. You're missing max

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry gave the solution:

```
select ou.username, 
    MAX(case when oup.propName='status' then oup.propValue end) as 'STATUS',
    MAX(case when oup.propName='picture' then oup.propValue end) as 'PICTURE'
from User ou
Join User_Properties oup
On ou.username = oup.username;
```